# How to substitute a Datatype with a Custom Identifier in C#?

Tags: c#

I have code like this:

```
private Dictionary<Int32, List<Command>> OutboundCommandSetsById;
private Dictionary<Int32, List<Command>> InboundCommentSetsById;

private List<Command> MyCommandSet;
```

I would like to declare a custom data type called `CommandSet` that is nothing more than a List of Commands.

It's plane old code substitution, so I could type `CommandSet` anywhere I would normally type `List<Command>`

How can I do this?

**FOLLOW-UP:** It has been suggested that my question only pertains to time-savings. I never said I only wanted to do this to save time. It's more a matter of code maintenance.

If I, or another user of my codebase, needs to create another container of `CommandSets`, I should be able to do so without having to know that a `CommandSet` is a `List<Command>`

I used the inheritance answer suggested. It works fine. I feel like it would perform better if C# offered preprocessor code substitution for cases like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it a class and you are good to go

```
class CommandSet : List<Command>
{
}
```

But I still recommend using `List<Command>` for more readable code

Comment: This action can be very usefull in WPF/UWP. You sometimes ahve to defined a Collection in XAML but can not use C# types. This way to "harden" the type is the workaround.

Comment: @Christopher if you read the question carefully you will see that OP is doing this to save himself some typing. it has nothing to do with WPF/UWP so I stand corrected

Comment: I never claimed you were incorrect. I just pointed out that there can be secondary benefits for going this way (rather then Type Aliasses).

Answer (score 1):

Try a [using alias directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) at the top of your file:

```
using System.Collections.Generics; 
using CommandSet = List<Command>;
```

Though this is generally frowned upon. It's usually considered better practice to just stick with `List<Command>`.

Comment: I can see why it is frowned upon for really short types. But if you got the Timer Ambiguity and have to use fully Qualified names (system.windows.forms.timer) I do not see any issue?

Comment: In most cases, ambiguity is the result of trying to do too much in the same file or class. But occasionally, yes, this is useful. That why it's there, and why I used weasel words like "usually" and "generally".